# How to create multiple empty classes in a single declaration?

Tags: python, class

As we can create multiple variables in a single line, such as:

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
print(x)
```

and the output would be 1,

I wonder if there is something similar to create multiple empty classes, so something like this, which I know is wrong, but just to let you have an idea of what I mean:

```
class X, Y, Z:
    pass
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think this is meaningful as class is an abstract thing. Three identical abstract things can be abstacted as one thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no special syntax to use a class definition this way. You *could* use the `type` constructor, something like:

```
>>> A, B, C = type('A', (object,), {}), type('B', (object,), {}), type('C', (object,), {})
>>> A, B, C
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>)
>>>
>>> A()
<__main__.A object at 0x10354d780>
>>> B()
<__main__.B object at 0x1038b1ef0>
>>> C()
<__main__.C object at 0x10354d780>
```

But I think that's hardly elegant, and it's unlikely you'll be able to keep the single line to a sane length. Just stick to the full class definitions.